# Altium: Is it okay to waive this constraint violation between two elements of the same electrical component?

Tags: pcb, altium, constraints

All of my electrical components are listed as having such clearance constraint violations when I open the *PCB Rules and Violations* window. I have tried lowering the minimum clearance from 0.254 mm to 0.127 mm in the minimum clearance matrix as part of the basic rules in the *Constraints Manager* window (I had read that 0.254 mm was considered too much on a different SE question).

As you can see in the image, I still have the <0.127mm violation between the two parts of the resistor. What is the cause of this violation and how to rectify it?

*Resistor with clearance violation*:
[image: Resistor with clearance violation]

Comment: Although this is a 'design' question (Yay!), it still specifically mentions Altium; and because of which I'll add this here:     This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the violation is that the two pads provide less clearance than the constraints that you have set up.

Either modify the footprint to suit the necessary constraints (if possible, depending on resistor model), or change to another resistor size, or lower the clearance requirements to whatever is needed for this footprint.

As of right now, if you try ordering PCB's, you will have to pay for the lower clearance.

There is no general "too much" or "too little" clearance to be set up in your constraints manager, it all boils down to the capabilities of your PCB manufacturer, and the price of the boards (lower clearance and track width => Generally higher cost). Or if you would have some isolation requirements for high voltage for example, but that's a completely different story.

Comment: Upon measuring the gap manually, it's 0.15mm, yet the violation <0.127mm still appears for the pads shown and for all other components.

Comment: Have you re-run DRC? Did your measurement snap to the grid, and not the pad edges?

Answer (score 2):

The violation is presented because these pads are closer than 0.127 mm (not because they are 0.127mm apart).

This can be rectified a number of ways, deciding which to pick is up to you (consider costs incurred, space available, part placement, etc...)

- Modify the rule, so the violation "*goes away*"
- Adjust the footprint so that the pads aren't so close
- Select a larger package

If you're looking at services like PCBWay, then clearance of 0.127mm is already likely to put you into a slightly increased price bracket, so changing the rule may not be a sensible decision.

We have no idea of scale from your screenshot - this could be a 1206 package with *massively* oversized pads. In which case, I'd suggest you follow the recommended land pattern for the package you're using.

For context, an 0201 passive will still typically have 0.3mm between the pads... if the footprint you've shown is well proportioned, then it's going to be a ***tiny*** part. If this is your first board, then I'd *strongly* suggest choosing a *much* larger package - perhaps 0805 or 1206.

---

To get some difinitive idea of how far apart these pads are, you can use the "*Measure*" tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>), and then click two points (i.e: the close edges). You can also calculate the gap from the pad dimensions and centers.